# Creating dyad event-year data from event participant-level data in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

All,

I'm trying to create dyad event-year data from event participant-level data using R and thought to ask for advice on how to handle this. The participant-level data set with which I'm working is fairly large and a bit complex (n > 6,000), so I'll offer an illustration of what I would like to do below.

My data look something like this.

```
casenum unit_id start  end initiatingside losses action joiner
    2     200   1952  1953              0      0      0      0
    2       2   1952  1953              1      0      7      0
    5     345   1953  1953              0      0      0      0
    5     300   1953  1953              1      0      8      0
    7     339   1956  1956              1      0     16      0
    7     200   1956  1956              0      0      7      0
    9     200   1960  1961              1      2     17      0
    9     740   1960  1961              0      1     17      0
   15     365   1958  1959              0      0      7      0
   15     210   1958  1959              0      0      7      0
   15     200   1958  1959              0      0      7      0
   15     225   1958  1959              0      1     10      0
   15     255   1958  1959              1      0     16      0
   15     310   1958  1959              0      0     16      1
   18     700   1963  1965              0      2     17      0
   18     200   1963  1965              1      0     17      0
   18      42   1964  1964              1      0      7      1
```

Assume I have six events with the following case numbers: 2, 5, 7, 9, 15, and 18. Each event pits one side against another. The first four cases are bilateral (2 vs. 200, 300 vs. 345, 200 vs. 339, and 200 vs. 740, respectively). The last two are multilateral events in which one of the participants is a joiner. Case no. 15 pits 255 vs. 200, 210, 225, 310, and 365, though 310 is not an original participant. Case no. 18 pits 42 and 200 vs. 700, though `unit_id = 42` is not an original participant.

Each observation at the participant level also includes an action taken, and losses incurred on an ordinal scale. The `initiatingside` variable codes whether the participant was on the side that initiated the event.

What I'd like is a dyad event-year data frame that looks something like this.

```
 casenum    pairid      year    losses    highestaction lowestaction     joiner
 2          1002200     1952      0         7                0               0
 2          1002200     1953      0         7                0               0
 5          1300345     1953      0         8                0               0
 7          1200339     1956      0         16               7               0
 9          1200740     1960      2         17               17              0
 9          1200740     1961      2         17               17              0
 15         1200255     1958      0         16               7               0
 15         1200255     1959      0         16               7               0
 15         1210255     1958      0         16               7               0
 15         1210255     1959      0         16               7               0
 15         1225255     1958      1         16               10              0
 15         1225255     1959      1         16               10              0
 15         1255310     1958      0         16               16              1
 15         1255310     1959      0         16               16              1
 15         1255365     1958      0         16               7               0
 15         1255365     1959      0         16               7               0
 18         1042700     1964      2         17               7               1
 18         1200700     1963      2         17               17              0
 18         1200700     1964      2         17               17              0
 18         1200700     1965      2         17               17              0
```

The `pairid` variable is a concatenation of the `unit_id` of one the participants with the `unit_id` of a participant on another side of the event. There are leading zeroes for `unit_id` of only one or two digits and a leading 1 to give it a unique `pairid` of seven digits (this should be easy with the `paste0` function). The lower `unit_id` comes first in the concatenation process, which, for my purposes, is important. The `year` variable captures an event-year.

The `losses` variable captures the highest value obtained by any of the participants in the event. The `highestaction` and `lowestaction` variables contain the highest and lowest `action` score (respectively) of one of the participants in the dyad. As such, they can be considered event-level information. The `joiner` variable captures if one or both of the participants in the event was not an original participant.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Sample code follows.

```
casenum <- c(2,2,5,5,7,7,9,9,15,15,15,15,15,15,18,18,18)
unit_id <- c(200,2,345,300,339,200,200,740,365,210,200,225,255,310,700,200,42)
start <- c(1952,1952,1953,1953,1956,1956,1960,1960,1958,1958,1958,1958,1958,1958,1963,1963,1964)
end <- c(1953,1953,1953,1953,1956,1956,1961,1961,1959,1959,1959,1959,1959,1959,1965,1965,1964)
initiatingside <- c(0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1)
losses <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0)
action <- c(0,7,0,8,16,7,17,17,7,7,7,10,16,16,17,17,7)
joiner <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1)

Data=data.frame(casenum=casenum,unit_id=unit_id,start=start,end=end,initiatingside=initiatingside,losses=losses,action=action,joiner=joiner)
Data
```

Comment: Why is the lowest action for the first case 7 and not 0?

Comment: Because I goofed. I apologize for that.